# Cannot read state when using async callbacks function in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I copied this function from a post here at stackoverflow, my goal was to be able to update a database and profile info right after the signup and before moving to a different route, the results are as I expect working however I can no longer access the state in the callback, can please someone assist me debug this code:

```
  signup = (e) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        if (userCredentials.user) {
          userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
            displayName: this.state.username,
            photoURL: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdVmHPt9SajdsWlAZWzqRXkd-SzmmO9bBUV45fLnw5giijsty3OA',
          }).then((s) => {
            fire.database()
              .ref(`master/${userCredentials.user.displayName}/setup/`)
              .update({
                bio: 'Be original',
              })
              .then(() => {
                window.location.reload();
              });
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ signupError: true, loading: false, });
      });
  }
```

The error happen in catch(error)

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

I suspect the issue comes from using multiple `.then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in `catch` is not your class, see different between normal function and arrow function. There're two way to solve your problem.

- First: using arrow function

```
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  this.setState({ signupError: true, loading: false, });
});
```

- Second: set local `self` variable for `this`

```
signup = (e) => {
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  e.preventDefault();
  const self = this; // It can be what ever you want, `self` is the most popular
  ...
}
```

then

```
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
  self.setState({ signupError: true, loading: false, });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS functions has its own `this` context.

In your case you use `this` context inside a callback. `this` context of the react component will be lost inside the callback. That is why catch block is unable to identify the `setState` method

To preserve and use `this` context inside the callback, assign `this` to a `local variable (named the variable as self in below example)` and access it inside the callback .

```
  signup = (e) => {
        var self= this;
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        e.preventDefault();
        fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
          .then((userCredentials) => {
            if (userCredentials.user) {
              userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
                displayName: this.state.username,
                photoURL: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdVmHPt9SajdsWlAZWzqRXkd-SzmmO9bBUV45fLnw5giijsty3OA',
              }).then((s) => {
                fire.database()
                  .ref(`master/${userCredentials.user.displayName}/setup/`)
                  .update({
                    bio: 'Be original',
                  })
                  .then(() => {
                    window.location.reload();
                  });
              })
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            self.setState({ signupError: true, loading: false, });
          });
      }
```

You can also use `arrow functions`, `arrow functions` doesnot have its own `this` context, so you'll be able to access `this` context of the outerscope

```
.catch((error)=> {
   console.log(error);
   this.setState({ signupError: true, loading: false, });
});
```

Comment: Helpful to add that this is equivalent to using an arrow function as the catch callback.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb arrow function is fine, but i wanted to explain why he got the error

Comment: You should not using `var`, consider to use `const` or `let`.

Comment: @namth iam using var inside function scope not block scope

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb some of us don't like arrow functions :)

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb i updated, should i remove my answer?, there is another answer posted with this similar info..

Comment: @divine, I think the discussion in comments is helpful than an answer :))

Comment: I wasn't questioning your likes/dislikes :). OP used a mixture of arrow functions and anonymous functions. So it would be helpful to explain how arrow functions are helping with the correct `this` in existing code and how they could in the catch block. It's your answer, it's your choice. :)